# Addition of values in second columns if the first column entry is same in UNIX

Tags: csv

I am trying to aggregate a file containing the following data in UNIX.
I need to add the amounts if the key is same.

```
Key,amount,date,Time
abc-xyz-12234,45,15-08-91,23:00
pqr-vgh-5241,15,15-08-91,21:00
abc-xyz-12234,35,15-08-91,23:00
pqr-vgh-5241,24,15-08-91,21:00
abc-xyz-12234,655,15-08-91,23:00
lkj-erf-8542,281,15-08-91,10:00
pqr-vgh-5241,40,15-08-91,21:00
```

Output should be as following

```
abc-xyz-12234,735,15-08-91,23:00
pqr-vgh-5241,79,15-08-91,21:00
lkj-erf-8542,281,15-08-91,10:00
```

I tried by the following command ,but it just gives me uniq

```
cat file | grep "abc-xyz-12234" | uniq
```

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution with `awk` could be:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
     NR != 1 { y[$1] += $2; $2 = y[$1]; x[$1] = $0; }
     END { for (i in x) { print x[i]; } }' file
```

The flaw is it won't preserve your order. So result could be:

```
pqr-vgh-5241,79,15-08-91,21:00
abc-xyz-12234,735,15-08-91,23:00
lkj-erf-8542,281,15-08-91,10:00
```

Comment: Order doesnt matters

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with awk:

```
#!/bin/sh
sort | awk -F, '
function result() {
    if ( key != "" ) {
            printf "%s,%d,%s\n", key, value, datetime;
    }
}
BEGIN { key = ""; value = 0; datetime = ""; }
$2 ~ /^[0-9]+/ {
    if ( $1 == key ) {
            value += $2;
    } else {
            result();
            key = $1;
            value = $2;
            datetime = $3 "," $4;
    }
}
END { result(); }
'
```

giving

```
./foo <input
abc-xyz-12234,735,15-08-91,23:00
lkj-erf-8542,281,15-08-91,10:00
pqr-vgh-5241,79,15-08-91,21:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way in Perl. Call it as such `./script file.ext`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my %data;
my @order;

while (<>){
    next if $. == 1;
    my @line = split /,/;
    if (defined $data{$line[0]}){
        $data{$line[0]}->[1] += $line[1];
    }
    else {
        $data{$line[0]} = \@line;
        push @order, $line[0];
    }
}

for (@order){
    print join(',', @{$data{$_}});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This uses Miller (`mlr`) to compute the sum of the `amount` field over each set of records grouped by the `Key`, `date`, and `Time` fields.  Miller will add the sum as a new field, `amount_sum`, at the end of the list of fields, so we also reorder the fields and relabel them.

```bash
mlr --csv \
    stats1 -a sum -f amount -g Key,date,Time then \
    reorder -f Key,amount_sum then \
    label Key,amount file
```

Output given the data in the question:

```
Key,amount,date,Time
abc-xyz-12234,735,15-08-91,23:00
pqr-vgh-5241,79,15-08-91,21:00
lkj-erf-8542,281,15-08-91,10:00
```

If you don't want the header in the output, use `mlr` with its `--headerless-csv-output` option.